# Cross-thread access to non-ui object in wpf

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I'm having some problems using a backgroundworker in a WPF app. Here's the situation:

I'm trying to do two things. First scanning a number of images and then use barcode recognition on the scanned images. I'm retrieving the scanned images as a list of BitmapSource objects and these should be available to my backgroundworker thread.

After some googling it seems most solutions are specific to communication with ui elements on the main thread because none of the solutions I've found have worked for me. I've tried using delegates and the dispatcher but to no avail.

I need the BitmapSources to create Bitmaps with them which is the input of the barcode recognition.

Thanks,

Kevin

Comment: so what is the actual problem you're facing?  can you post some code?

Comment: A BackgroundWorker thread has access to any class members. Maybe you should post some code to show an example of what's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WPF, all `DispatcherObjects` (not only UI elements) can be accessed only from the thread that created them. `BitmapSource` inherits (indirectly) from `DispatcherObject`, so it follows this rule. However, it also inherits from `Freezable`, and `Freezable` objects can be accessed from another thread *if they are frozen*.

So, after your `BitmapSource` is initialized, you can call `Freeze` on it, and it will be accessible from other threads.

Comment: what about other UI Elements? It appears elements such as `TextBlock` do not inherit from `DispatcherObject`.  :(

Comment: @conqenator, yes it does (indirectly)... check out the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.aspx) (in WPF, not in Silverlight)